# ComboBox ActionListener Java

Tags: java, swing, oop, combobox, actionlistener

I have this ComboBox and what I want is whenever I change the selection, that the number corresponding to the selection to be placed in a text field. Initially, the text field is blank, when I select something, it displays it well, but it does not change according to my selection.

Here is the action method :

```
 private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
    jTextField1.setText("");
    Iterator<Product> it = warehouse.getStock().iterator();
    if(!warehouse.getStock().isEmpty())
    {
    x:  while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Product temp = it.next();
            if(temp.getName().equals(jComboBox5.getSelectedItem()))
            {
                jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(temp.getQuantity()));
                break x;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'll add extra code if needed. What can I do?

Comment: *"I'll add extra code if needed."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: where is this method called from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You receive an `ActionEvent` while you should be receiving an `ItemEvent` by registering an `ItemListener` if you want to react on changes in selection. You can then check have code like (not tested):

```
if ( event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED ){
  jTextField1.setText( Integer.toString( (Product) event.getItem() ) );
}
```